# How can I open submenu beside a css vertical menu?

Tags: css, menu

I need to make a vertical menu using CSS and `<ul>` `<li>` tags. But when ever I put the cursor on a link that contains submenu, other main items move to another place.
This is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc6m4/1/).
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Terry, I have tried what you can see in my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the sub menu `position: relative` (which still makes it part of the flow) make the containing `li` `position: relative` and the `menu_sub` `position: absolute` with the appropriate `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` settings:

```
#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
#menu_sub {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    list-style:none;
    display:none;
    left: 70%;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc6m4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Explosion Pills response works. As does this:

By floating the sub menu, you can also break it you of the normal flow, but still retain it's relationship to the parent UL:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc6m4/4/

```
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left; 0;
}
```

Then you adjust the position using top, left, right, etc. In my example above, I used a negative `top` position to clear the height of the parent list item so they start at roughly the same position.